# In Javascript console.log I am not getting the result

Tags: javascript, undefined, console.log

I want **console.log** to print only **firstname** if **lastname** was **undefined**, instead I get firstname + undefined on the console. What could I change in the code so it only gives me firstname or lastname if one of them is undefined without printing the word 'undefined' in the console, and if both are defined to print them both. This is the code I am trying:

```
    document.getElementById("runButton").onclick = function run() {
        var lastName = "arm";
        var firstName;
        function Greeting(firstName, lastName) {
            if (lastName = 'undefined') {
                console.log("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
            } else if (firstName = 'undefiend') {
                console.log("hello, " + lastName + "!!");
            } else {
                console.log("hello, " + firstName + lastName + "!!!");
            }
        }
        Greeting(firstName + " " + lastName);
    };
```

Comment: You're using `=` for comparison when you should be using `===` or `==`. Also, you put `'undefined'` in quotes. Remove those. `if (lastName == undefined) {`

Comment: Use `==` for if-else statement

Comment: It should also be `Greeting(firstName,lastName);`, not `Greeting(firstName + " " + lastName);`

Comment: ...and you shoud use if(typeof(lastName)=="undefined")...

Comment: @Cracker0dks: No, they really shouldn't.

Comment: @squint very clever answer... without reason. with typeof u can prevent error throws!

Comment: `if(!!lastName)` also works if you want to check var is not undefined and not null

Comment: @Cracker0dks: Well then you might as well wrap your entire program in a `try/catch` if you think burying errors is actually a good idea. If you're using undeclared variables, that's a bug to fix, not hide.

Comment: ...and *so* many people mistype the `typeof` technique, that they end up introducing even *more* bugs. Yeah, they really shouldn't do that.

Comment: @squint ok, if you are sure your var should exist you are right. ty :)

Comment: @Cracker0dks: Yes, there are some edge cases where avoiding those errors makes sense, like when there may or may not be a global defined, though `window.SomeGlobal` works in that case too. Either way is good in that situation. :)

Answer (score 4):

The condition should `lastName===undefined` not `lastName= 'undefined'`. You can either use `==`(Equal to) or `===`(Strict equal to) to check as the operator. `=` is assignment operator.

```js
 document.getElementById("runButton").onclick = function run() {
    var lastName = "arm";
    var firstName;
    function Greeting(firstName, lastName) {
        if(typeof firstName !== 'undefined' &&  typeof lastName !== 'undefined'){
            console.log("hello, " + firstName + " " +  lastName + "!!!");
        } else if ( typeof lastName !== 'undefined') {
            console.log("Hello, " + lastName + "!");
        } else if (typeof firstName !== 'undefiend') {
            console.log("hello, " + firstName + "!!");
        } 
    }
    Greeting(firstName,lastName);
};
```

```html
<button id="runButton">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: While this definitely corrects the bugs, I'd note that the logic is probably wrong, since it prints the `firstName` if the `lastName` is `undefined`, but doesn't actually know if the `firstName` has a useful value to print. But it follows what the OP was doing, so good enough.

Comment: That's true. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Check your conditions, it has typo. Also

```
function Greeting(firstName, lastName) {
            if (lastName == undefined) {
                console.log("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
            } else if (firstName == undefined) {
                console.log("hello, " + lastName + "!!");
            } else {
                console.log("hello, " + firstName + lastName + "!!!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: oops!, corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single `=` use a double `==`. Currently you set the lastName equal to `undefined`, by using two equal signs you are comparing. So change to this. Also undefined doesn't need to be in apostrophes.

Comment: Never use a  "==" instead use "==="

Comment: @IceBox That's a completely different discussion.

Comment: @IceBox: Never? That's over the top.

Comment: @squint best practise!!!

Comment: @IceBox: Best practice is to understand the tools you have at your disposal, and use them how and when is appropriate. Saying "never" to useful operators isn't a very good practice.

Comment: @squint Javascript has a lot of your so called useful operators or features, which we should never use

Comment: @IceBox: Well that's really just nonsense. Amazing how people try to reduce programming down to a tiny set of rigid rules.

Comment: @squint I don't have time to have an argument with you on this, bad practices may lead to many undesirable results which are hard to debug, thats why people developed coding and design patterns. Learning things is a different thing but using them is different

Comment: @IceBox: There's a big difference between adopting practices in your coding and telling people to "never" do something. The `==` operator is extremely useful in some cases. Hard to imagine arguing against being informed and knowledgeable.

Comment: @squint These are the words of Douglas Crockford,
"The lack of transitivity is alarming. My advice is to "never" use the evil twins. Instead, always use === and !==". If you use any JS lint, it will also give you an error. I am not going to reply any more.

Comment: @IceBox: You're going to need to do better than quote Doug Crockford of all people. And quit getting so emotional about all this. You're acting like it's religion or something. Absolutism in programming may give you comfort, but it isn't your friend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139597/discussion-between-ice-box-and-squint).

Answer (score 0):

You are using = instead of == (= means assignment and == means comparison)

```js
 document.getElementById("runButton").onclick = function run() {
        var lastName = 'arm';
        var firstName;
        function Greeting(firstName, lastName) {
            if (lastName === undefined) {
                console.log("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
            } else if (firstName === undefined) {
                console.log("hello, " + lastName + "!!");
            } else {
                console.log("hello, " + firstName + lastName + "!!!");
            }
        }
        Greeting(firstName , lastName);
    };
```

```html
<button id="runButton">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use === instead of == to compare the type as well.

firstName === undefiend

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("runButton").onclick = function run() {
    var lastName = "arm";
    var firstName;
    mygreeting = Greeting(firstName, lastName);
    console.log(mygreeting);
};
function Greeting(firstName, lastName) {
    if (typeof lastName === 'undefined') {
        return ("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
    } else if (typeof firstName === 'undefiend') {
        return ("hello, " + lastName + "!!");
    } else {
        return ("hello, " + firstName + lastName + "!!!");
    }
}
```

You'd want your function to return a result and then assign the return of your function to a variable, then use that variable for something, in this care in console.log();

Comment: Why the downvotes? isn't what i said correct?

Comment: Examine your code more closely.

Comment: Please tell me what's wrong, I examined it, even with lint

Comment: You're comparing `lastName` and `firstName` to the *string* `"undefined"`. You need to remove those quotes.

Comment: oh right I guess I always use `typeof firstname == 'undefined'`

Comment: If you want, but the problem is that people mistype that technique. That's how this bug originated in the first place. People end up doing `firstName == "undefined"` or `typeof firstName == undefined`, both of which are wrong. Safer is to simply do `firstName == undefined`.

Comment: yep, or `firstName == null`

Comment: Yeah, that's usually what I use since I nearly always want to check both `undefined` and `null` at the same time. Nice, short and clear.

Comment: @squint what if the string is empty, firstName = '';,
The common thing between all three null, undefined and empty is that they all are falsy, so we can directly use 
if(firstName)

Comment: @IceBox: That isn't how the [*Abstract equality comparison algorithm*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison) works. It isn't based on truthy/falsey evaluation but instead walks through a much more complex algorithm. Within that algorithm, `null` and `undefined` will be equal to themselves and each other, but no other value. I do agree that the complexity of the algorithm can lead to some WTF situations, but there are other places where it fits the bill just right. Probably 99% of the time where I use it is `null/undefined` comparisons.

Comment: ...though you're right that for `if (firstName)`, all three would be considered the same. Because then it is a truthy evaluation.